# remove and append iframe when src refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

The code below creates a 10 second delay, and then draws the captcha iframe to the page.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#contain").delay(10000).queue(function(next) {
            $(this).append('<iframe src="captcha.php"></iframe>');
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="contain"></div>
```

When the correct captcha is entered, the iframe captcha page refreshes and a new captcha is presented.

What I would like to happen is every time captcha.php is refreshes, I would like the iframe removed from source again, and the then readded again after 10 seconds.

Originally I was just using a switch inside the captcha to toggle the parent iframe for 10 seconds, but that is relatively easy for the user to just set the display without waiting for the timer - so I am seek a better solution.

It seems the best way, if I can manage to get it working, would be to add and remove the iframe with a 10 second delay on the add.

Comment: better way to do this is in your `captcha.php`, refresh the image for a regular time interval

Comment: A refreshed image wouldn't really solve the problem. The page refreshes when the captcha is answered correctly. At that point we need to hide the captcha from the user for 10 seconds.

Comment: You can send postMessage message from captcha.php to the parent page to hide and show the iframe.

Comment: Originally I was just using a switch inside the captcha to toggle the parent iframe for 10 seconds, but that is relatively easy for the user to just set the display without waiting for the timer. So a simple toggle won't work. And if I remove the frame from the src, then obviously the frame is gone so the source won't reload. I am thinking I need to name this as a function, then call the function when the page loads, and from the src, recall the function and remove the iframe again, just not sure how I would do that.